# How to use the value of variable from if/else tree as value of variable for a while loop afterwards

Tags: java

Here is my program code as I have it written so far. It's saying I haven't initialized answer. I want to use the value of answer after the if/else tree executes to convert the number into asterisks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please enter a formula of this form:operator,operand,operand(ex. add,2,2):");
        // wanted to change things but was not sure how far I was allowed to go so I used commas instead of spaces
        //was trying to split with a delimiter but kept getting an error [Ljava.lang.String;@55e83f9
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String formula = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(formula);
        String oper = formula.substring(0,3);
        System.out.println(oper);
        String fnum = formula.substring(4,5);
        System.out.println(fnum);
        String snum = formula.substring(6,7);
        System.out.println(snum);
        double freal = Integer.parseInt(fnum);
        System.out.println(freal);
        double sreal = Integer.parseInt(snum);
        double answer;
        if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("add") == true){
            answer = freal+sreal;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        else if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("subtract") == true){
                 answer = freal-sreal;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        else if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("multiply") == true){
                 answer = freal*sreal;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        else if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("divide") == true){
                 answer = freal/sreal;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("not valid.");

        while(answer > 0){
            System.out.print("*");
            answer--;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Is this Homework? if so you need to tag it as such.

Comment: Please tag this question as "homework".

Answer (score 2):

Because in the final `else` branch, you don't assign a value to `answer`.  If that is the tree that's executed, then when you get to the `while` loop, it will be undefined.  You can fix this by initially initializing `answer` to some value or by making sure every branch of the `if/else` tree assigns `answer` a value.

**Edit** To address your question, change

```
double answer;
```

To

```
double answer = 0.0;
```

That will fix the problem.

Comment: So i removed the last else branch so answer would have a value and it still giving me the same not initialized error. is answer not already initilized and declared? How would i write it so i would use the final value of answer as the initialized value for the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the error you are getting is a good start in working out what the problem is:

> Project5.java:41: variable answer might not have been initialized

So you should initialize the variable `answer`

**Edit:** To be even clearer, change the line that says `double answer;` to `double answer = 0.0;` thereby **initializing** the `answer` variable. That is what the compiler is complaining about and is the only change you need to make in order for the code to compile and execute. By the way, you will have more errors to deal with after this because although you are allowing the operator to be 3 characters, you are trying to compare this with a longer word in some cases. So `add` works but `subtract` does not.

Comment: So i removed the last else branch so answer would have a value and it still giving me the same not initialized error. is answer not already initilized and declared? How would i write it so i would use the final value of answer as the initialized value for the while loop?

Comment: Correct. `answer` is _not_ initialized. You just need to give it a starting (default) value, for example `0.0`

Comment: Removing the last `else` doesn't change the fact that `answer` isn't given a value. To fix the code, either declare `answer` as `double answer = 0.0` (or some other aptly chosen value), or set `answer` to be `0` in your final `else` clause, or you can simply return from `main` in your final `else` clause. You've got a lot of options - all you have to ensure is that it is impossible for the program to reach your while loop until `answer` has been given a value.

Comment: doing that doesnt return the asterisks i want to print out because i am giving answer the value of 0. I want answer to spit out the amount of asterisks = the final value of answer from the if else tree.

Comment: i think i am being misunderstood or i am misunderstanding. I need the last value of answer to be converted to asterisks via the while loop. if i declare answer to be =0.0 this returns nothing. I need that value to be intilized as the last value of answer from the if else tree. please explain the correct syntax to accomplish this someone:(

Comment: @david: _what_ last value? If the user doesn't enter a valid operator, `answer` has no value. You need to decide what you want your program to print when no valid operator has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing is that you have to initialize answer: `double answer = 0.0;`